# Why does the Dark Theme in Windows 10 does not display filenames in light colors?

Tags: windows-10, colors, themes

I have installed Windows 10 and set the theme to Dark.
However, althought the names of the drives are in white, everything contained inside the hard drives are with black names, which is extremely disgusting to look at when you are in Dark Mode. I have Googled for this but other people do not seem to have this problem.

Can anybody solve this problem?

My Computer:

[image: This is in My Computer]]

Inside the drive D (and the subfolders):

[image: This is inside the drive D (and the subfolders)]]

Comment: You appear to have applied some non-standard customization. Undo them first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This probably is a rendering bug in Windows. Usually, a reboot is enough to fix this. If a reboot doesn't work, check if other customizations are applied to your system and remove those.